# Why it's not working numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline

Tags: python, runtime-error, numba

I had working code and wanted to do it more faster, i used numba to do it.
my code decrypts gronsfeld by guessing the key and comparing it with a dictionary. I wanted to speed up this code, if you know another way to speed it up write me)

```
import string
from numba import njit, prange
import time
string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
alph = string.ascii_uppercase


def decrypt(message, key):
    return algo(message, key, -1)
def algo(text, k, op):
    k *= len(text) // len(k) + 1
    return ''.join(alph[alph.index(j) + int(k[i]) * op] for i, j in enumerate(text))
def encrypt(message, key):
    return algo(message, key, 1)




word_toDecode = 'NHUDMOVUHB'.upper()
f = open('words.txt')
dictionary = f.readlines()

@njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def brute():
    for x in prange(100):
        s = decrypt(word_toDecode, str(x))
        for line in dictionary:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            if s.lower() == line.lower():
                print(line)
        print(x)
```

As error i got this. HELP ! :)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skigi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    brute()
  File "C:\Users\skigi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\skigi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'decrypt': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "main.py", line 26:
def brute():
    <source elided>
    for x in prange(100):
        s = decrypt(word_toDecode, str(x))
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Numba complains about the `decrypt` function because it is not JITed. `@njit` can only execute Numba built-in functions or other `@njit`-ed functions. You need to use `@njit` recursively on other functions like `decrypt` or `algo`.

Note that Numba is not optimized to compute strings yet. Thus, the resulting code may be slower than CPython.